# How do I knit child documents with parameters into a main RMarkdown document?

Tags: r-markdown, parameter-passing, knitr

I have a parameterized RMarkdown file, `parameterized.Rmd`, with the following contents.

````
---
title: "Parameterized report"
output: html_document
params:
  input_df: NULL
---
```{r sec1}
head(params$input_df[, 1:2])
```
````

I can knit it from the console using `rmarkdown::render`, generating distinct documents for distinct dataframe inputs.  This works as expected.

```
rmarkdown::render("parameterized.Rmd", 
                params = list(input_df = mtcars), 
                output_file = "cars.html")

rmarkdown::render("parameterized.Rmd", 
                  params = list(input_df = iris), 
                  output_file = "iris.html")
```

I would like to have each of these results be child documents to a common document.  My first attempt is with `knitr::knit_child`, but it does not take `params` as an argument.  So this failed.

````
---
title: "Main report"
output: html_document
---


```{r test-cars}
knitr::knit_child("parameterized.Rmd", envir = environment(), quiet = T,
                  params = list(input_df = mtcars))
```
````

How may I knit together child documents which require parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What worked for me (derived from the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html) once I properly understood it.):

Instead of using the `params` field in the YAML header, set the values of the parameters inside the main document and call `cat` on the output of `knitr::knit_child`.  The below files achieved the desired result.

### parameterized.Rmd

````
---
title: "Parameterized report"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
head(df[, 1:2])
```
````

### main.Rmd

````
---
title: "Main report"
output: html_document
---

# mtcars
```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
df <- mtcars 
cat(
  knitr::knit_child('parameterized.Rmd', envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
  )
```

# iris
```{r iris, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
df <- iris 
cat(
  knitr::knit_child('parameterized.Rmd', envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
  )
```
````

Knitting `main.Rmd` applied the parameterized report to each dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually also "overwrite" parameters in the child document if you run it in a child environment where you manually add the `params` variable. It looks like the params set in YAML in the child document won't be used if you `knitr::knit_child()`. So this should work:

### parameterized.Rmd

````
---
title: "Parameterized report"
output: html_document
params:
  input_df: NULL
---

```{r sec1}
head(input_df[, 1:2])
```
````

### main.Rmd

````
---
title: "Main report"
output: html_document
---

# mtcars
```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
e1 <- new.env()
e1$params$input_df <- mtcars

cat(
  knitr::knit_child('parameterized.Rmd', envir = e1, quiet = TRUE)
  )
```

# iris
```{r iris, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
e2 <- new.env()
e2$params$input_df <- iris 

cat(
  knitr::knit_child('parameterized.Rmd', envir = e2, quiet = TRUE)
  )
```
````

---

The outcome is quite similar. However, the child report will now be evaluated in a child environment. If you want to have variables from the child report to be available in the main report you have to set them via "<<-". Like this your global environment won't get flushed with variables that you might not need there. I use this for a child report that can also be knitted as a standalone version:

### SeparateReport.Rmd

````
---
title: "Separate Report"
output: html_document
params:
  fullprint: TRUE
---

```{r, eval=fullprint}
# do this only if knitting the full version is intended
...

```

```{r}
# always include this chunk
...
some_var <<- some_local_result
```
````

### Main.Rmd

````
---
title: "Main Report"
output: html_document
---

```{r child1}
e <- new.env()
e$params$fullprint <- FALSE

knitr::knit_child("SeparateReport.Rmd", envir = e)
print(some_var)
```
````

---

Or you can pass the parameter from the main file

### Main.Rmd

````
---
title: "Main Report"
output: html_document
params:
  fullprint: FALSE
---

```{r child1}
knitr::knit_child("SeparateReport.Rmd")
print(some_var)
```
````