# Compile multiple instances of SAME markdown into ONE pdf

Tags: r

My data file includes a long list of case, one row per case. I want to produce a long PDF report, that would include one page per case, each page would contain the same table and graphs, but for a different case.

I understand I should have a 'child' markdown (one page), for example, `childfile.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "case number `r params$case[1]`"
output: pdf_document
params:
    case: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
---

```{r part1, echo=FALSE}
params$case[2:4]
```


```{r part2, echo=FALSE}
params$case[5:7]
```
````

and render it using a loop in a 'parent' markdown, for example, `parentfile.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "all cases"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r parent, include=FALSE}

df = data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,4),
               var1   = c(1,2,3,4),
               var2   = c(1,2,3,4),
               var3   = c(1,2,3,4),
               var4   = c(1,2,3,4),
               var5   = c(1,2,3,4),
               var6   = c(1,2,3,4)               )

for ( i in 1:4 ){
  rmarkdown::render("childfile.Rmd", 
                    params = list(case = as.vector(df[i,])))
}
```
````

However,  this results in a blank pdf for the parent, and a second pdf for the chid, containg only the last case.

How can the complete set of child PDFs can be rendered into one PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two difficulties here.  The first is that `rmarkdown::render()` will compile the document by itself; to compile the child document within the parent, `knitr::knit_child()` will do the trick.  In the example below, I used the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685397/10898875) to feed the appropriate case into each iteration of the child: by using a variable instead of parameters.

The second is that a LaTeX document, to my knowledge, can have only one title.  So we can't give each child document its own title; but we can give each one its own heading (whose style can be easily customized if you want).

## Child document

Note that the child document isn't a standalone markdown file; it's just enough for the material we want to render.  Instead of referring to a parameter called `case`, we refer to a variable of the same name.

````
# case `r unname(unlist(case[1]))`

```{r}
case[2:4]
```


```{r}
case[5:7]
```

\pagebreak
````

## Parent document

The loop iterates over the first four rows of `df`.  For each row, it sets the variable `case` (which the child document will need) and then uses `knitr::knit_child()` to process the child.  We send the knit output back into the parent document with `cat()`; note also that this chunk crucially sets the `results='asis'` option.

````
---
title: "all cases"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
df = data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,4),
                var1   = c(1,2,3,4),
                var2   = c(1,2,3,4),
                var3   = c(1,2,3,4),
                var4   = c(1,2,3,4),
                var5   = c(1,2,3,4),
                var6   = c(1,2,3,4))
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r parent, results='asis'}
for(i in 1:4) {
  case = df[i,]
  cat(knitr::knit_child("childfile.Rmd", envir = environment(), quiet = T))
  cat("\n")
}
```
````