# Pass body of Rmarkdown chunk as argument to child document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've designed an expandable info box for my blog (which is rendered from Rmarkdown) which I want to use as a template.

At the momentan I just write more or less plain HTML in the main Rmarkdown document, as below:

```
<div class="info" markdown="1">
<details>
  <summary class="info-header" markdown="1">
  Title <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </summary>
    <p class="info-details">
    Here goes the body
    </p>
  </details>
</div>
```

With some CSS this renders nicely:

[image]

Ideally I would like to replace the HTML above by using some kind of child document which has a `title` argument to specify the title, and (and this is the tricky part) which passes the whole body of the Rmarkdown chunk to the body section of the child document. So ideally the above HTML could be written as.

````
```{r, child = "info_box.Rmd", title = "My Title"}
Here goes the body
```
````

Is this possible? I understand how to insert a child document, also with arguments, and when looking at `rmarkdown::hmtl_document()` I do get a glimpse of how the use real arguments like `title`, but can we pass the body of the Rmarkdown chunk down to the child so that it is used at a specific place? Do we need a custom output format for this and how would it look like?

Any help appreciated. I'm also open for other solutions, but it would be more than great if the ideal approach above would work.

Comment: What would be content of `info_box.Rmd`,  just some text  to be inserted in a info box?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving another answer which is based on [knitr output hooks](https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/#output-hooks) and Pandoc Lua filter that also works fine for `rmarkdown::html_document` (and probably a better approach than the previous one).

Pass the child document path to the chunk option `child_into_box` and specify the box title to option `box_title`. One very important detail to note is that **you must at least insert a comment in that chunk**, otherwise for an empty chunk the redefined knitr source hook does not work.

````
---
title: Passing Child document Text to Info box.
output: 
  html_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - --lua-filter=box_wrap.lua
---

## Rmarkdown

Some text

```{r}
#| echo: false
library(knitr)

default_source_hook <- knit_hooks$get('source')

knit_hooks$set(
  source = function(x, options) {
    if(is.null(options$child_into_box))
      default_source_hook(x, options)
    else {
      res <- knitr::knit_child(input = options$child_into_box, envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
      div_start = paste0("::: {wrap-box=true box-title='", options$box_title, "'}")
      paste0(div_start, "\n", unlist(res), "\n", "\n:::\n")
    }
  }
)
```

Some more text

```{r}
#| child_into_box: info_box.Rmd
#| box_title: my info test box

# comment
```
````

**box_wrap.lua**

```
local str = pandoc.utils.stringify

local template_info_box_p1 = [[
<div class="note" markdown="1">
<details>
  <summary class="note-header" markdown="1">
  %s<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </summary>
<div class="note-details">
]]

local template_info_box_p2 = [[
</div>
  </details>
</div>
]]

function Div(el)
  if el.attributes['wrap-box'] then
    local title = str(el.attributes['box-title'])
    local info_box = string.format(template_info_box_p1, title)
    local info_box_rb1 = pandoc.RawBlock('html', info_box)
    local info_box_rb2 = pandoc.RawBlock('html', template_info_box_p2)
    el.content:insert(1, info_box_rb1)
    el.content:insert(info_box_rb2)
    return el
  end
end
```

---

[image: screenshot of rendered output]

Comment: I think this answers perfectly my question, thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably we could make our own output function based on the desired output format and add the `knit_hook` to this new output function. Then we can just create info boxes based on a chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Since the output format is HTML, a possible solution based on [pandoc lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) and Javascript is as follows,

**main.Rmd**

````
---
title: Passing Child document Text to Info box.
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      after_body: infoBox.html
    pandoc_args:
      - --lua-filter=info_box.lua
---

## Rmarkdown

::: {.info-box title="My new Title" #first}
:::


::: {.add-to-info #first}
```{r}
#| child: info_box.Rmd
```

Also some random text to be inserted into that info box
:::


::: {.info-box title="More info box" #second}
:::


::: {.add-to-info #second}
```{r}
#| child: info_box.Rmd
```

Also some random text to be inserted into that info box
:::
````

---

So to add contents from child-document to the info box you need to do two thing.

- Firstly, create a pandoc div (using `:::`) with class `.info-box`, give it title that you want and give a unique id (suppose, `#first`) so that we could use it to insert the content of a child document to this specific info box.
- secondly, wrap the code chunk with the `child` option with another pandoc div associated with class `.add-to-info` and use the id of the info box to where you want the content of this child document to be.

Now following these two steps you can generate as many as info box you want.

---

**info_box.Rmd**

````
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget, etiam, a metus purus sit quisque elit, suscipit. 

```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
plot(1:10)
```

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

(no need to use `title` or `output` for the child document, it simply contains the body text)

---

**info_box.lua**

```
local template_info_box_p1 = [[
<div class="info" markdown="1">
<details>
  <summary class="info-header" markdown="1">
  %s <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </summary>
    <p class="info-details" id="%s">
]]

local template_info_box_p2 = [[
    </p>
  </details>
</div>
]]


function Div(el)
  if el.classes:includes('info-box') then
    local title = el.attributes['title']
    local id = el.identifier
    local info_box_p1 = string.format(template_info_box_p1, title, id)
    local info_box_html_p1 = pandoc.RawBlock('html', info_box_p1)
    local child_content = el.content
    local info_box_html_p2 = pandoc.RawBlock('html', template_info_box_p2)
    return pandoc.Div({info_box_html_p1, info_box_html_p2})
  end
end
```

**infoBox.html**

```
<script>
  function add_to_info() {
    let childs = document.querySelectorAll("div.add-to-info");
    let info_box = document.querySelectorAll('p.info-details');
    childs.forEach(el => {
      info_box.forEach(box => {
        if (el.id === box.id) {
          box.appendChild(el);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  window.onload = add_to_info();
</script>
```

---

**A portion of the rendered ouput**

[image: output screenshot]

---

Note that, this output lacks the necessary CSS styles along with fontawesome icon, which you can handle accordingly using the embedded classes `info-header` and `info-details`.

Comment: Ok this is really cool and even better then I anticipated. The last thing that really would be great to achieve - and which I didn't have on my mind - is to add R code chunks to the `info_box.Rmd`. At the moment I'm just using a headerless Rmd file and write text there, if we'd were to include a code chunk, would we need to specifcy a header with a certain output format?

Comment: And by the way, where can I read up on customizing Rmarkdown with lua? And what it is the chunk between those three colons `:::` called?

Comment: To know more  about Lua filter you can read [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/vignettes/lua-filters.html) and the whole of docs of pandoc lua filter (that I linked with the answer). The `:::` are known as pandoc Divs (they are converted to HTML divs when output format is html) and the `.info-box` is the associated class of the div.

Comment: And No, even if you added code or more, still you would not need to give output format, because Lua filter is simply manipulating the pandoc AST (which comes before the output format; you would get the idea once you go through the above links).

Comment: And I think that it might be possible to extend my answer to support child document with more text, codes, figures etc rather just with simple paragraph, But my limited lua knowledge would not allow me to write lua filter for more general case :)

Comment: @TimTeaFan, see the updated answer. This is more general, will for what ever you put in a child document (Hopefully) but requires javascript.

Comment: thanks for your updated answer! It  look very promising, I haven't yet got it working, because my output format is not `html_document` but `md_document` and here the rendering is different. The `</p>` of the second code block is interpreted as `code` and then the box stops. I need to update my question (which I will do later) but if you switch the output format you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I wish you had said this earlier :-). Anyway, yes update your question with the exact thing you want. : )

Comment: Thanks for offering that, but I think you have already answered my initial question how to pass the body of a child into functions processing it. So my question is answered. I just noticed too late, that my ideal solution shouldn't have been a code chunk, but  a separate Rmd file which contains the content of the info box. For this I have opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75251741/wrap-rmarkdown-child-in-additional-html). I think it is easier to answer than the question in this thread.

Comment: I will also award the bounty, but keep it open a bit longer as other valid answers to this question ("passing the body of an Rmarkdown chunk as argument") might be posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a first answer looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685397/9349302):

I could create a template `info_box.Rmd` like:

```
---
title: ""
output: rmarkdown::html_document
---

<div class="note" markdown="1">
<details>
  <summary class="note-header" markdown="1">
    `r title`<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </summary>
    <p class="note-details">
      `r body`
    </p>
  </details>
</div>
```

And then replace the intial HTML from my post with:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
title <- "My new Title"
body  <- "The new body"
cat(
  knitr::knit_child("info_box.Rmd",
                    envir = environment(),
                    quiet = TRUE)
  )
```
````

And it works:

[image: x]

However, I'd still prefer a solution looking like this:

````
```{r, child = "info_box.Rmd", title = "My Title"}
Here goes the body
```
````

Comment: You could do that with a chunk hook.  See https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/ .

Comment: @user2554330 This looks promising, I read through it, but still need to get my head around.

Comment: Once you get it to work, you should edit your answer to include your solution.  If you run into problems, edit your question to show your progress and explain the issues.