# Wrap Rmarkdown child in additional HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an Rmd document containing a child document.

**main.Rmd**

````
---
output: hugodown::md_document
title: "Main Title"
---

# Heading

Some text

```{r}
# some code goes here

1 + 1
```

Some more text

```{r, child="my_info_box.Rmd"}
```
````

**my_info_box.Rmd**

````
<div class="note" markdown="1">
<details>
  <summary class="note-header" markdown="1">
  "my info test box"<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </summary>
<div class="note-details">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget, etiam, a metus purus sit quisque elit, suscipit. 

```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```

</div>
  </details>
</div>
````

I want the child document to be less cluttered with HTML and ideally look like this:

New ideal **my_info_box.Rmd**

````
---
title: "my info test box"
---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eget, etiam, a metus purus sit quisque elit, suscipit. 

```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

The output should stay the same, so two things should happen:

(1) the child document should be "automatically" wrapped in:

```
<div class="note" markdown="1">
<details>
  <summary class="note-header" markdown="1">
  "my info test box"<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </summary>
<div class="note-details">

... child documents content goes here ...

</div>
  </details>
</div>
```

(2) and the `title` argument of the child document should be automatically placed inside the info box right before the icon.

I'm currently using `hugodown::md_document()` as output which doesn't support any pandoc options. You can use `rmarkdown::md_document()` to answer this question as the `hugodown::md_document()` function can be easily extended (I have already done so on a [forked branch](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/hugodown/tree/toc)). Then the use of `includes` or `pandoc_args` is possible.

Disclaimer: I have asked a similar question, but with a different desired output format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75195909/pass-body-of-rmarkdown-chunk-as-argument-to-child-document/75226070?noredirect=1#comment132774044_75226070). Later I noticed that my desired output should be a separate child document instead of a  chunk.

Comment: It seems `hugodown::md_document` is creating an HTML output, right? Then can't javascript be used in this case too like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75226070/10858321)?

Comment: @shafee yes your javascript function was working in `md_document()`. It was only the split between two parts which led to troubles. If there is a JS way to wrap the whole output that would be great.

Comment: @shafee But I have to add, that I used my forked version of `hugodown::md_document()`. To just test if something is working or not we can use `rmarkdown::md_document()` which has much more support of arguments.

Comment: So If I install `hugodown` from your forked repo, `pandoc_arg` should be available, right?

Comment: You can install the "toc" branch with `remotes::install_github("timteafan/hugodown@toc")` then `pandoc_args ` is available. If it is not working as expected, I'll have a look at the implementation and you could use `rmarkdown::md_document()` instead.

Comment: Yes, already done that, but one funny thing is that `hugodown::md_document` creates directly html tags that can not be manipulated by lua filter. So now attempting with javascript completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `hugodown::md_document` creates HTML output, you can use javascript to create the drop-down box (i.e. HTML DOM Nodes) and then insert the child document content into that box.

So simply wrap the chunk with `child` chunk option with a pandoc Div with `info-box` class and also with a title attribute (which will be the title of the box) and rest will be handled by the js script in the `wrap_box.html` file.

---

Note: I think, it is not possible to use the child-document title (or any meta information of the child document) inside the parent document, because only the document-body (blocks of the body) of child-document are inserted into the parent document via the `child` option, all the meta information are discarded.

---

````
---
title: "Main Title"
output:
  hugodown::md_document:
    includes:
      after_body: wrap_box.html
---

# Heading

Some text

```{r}
# some code goes here

1 + 1
```

## Some more text

::: {.info-box title="My new Title"}
```{r}
#| child: my_info_box.Rmd
```
:::

## And More

::: {.info-box title="More info"}
```{r}
#| child: my_info_box.Rmd
```
:::
````

The same **my_info_box.Rmd** file as given in question is used in this answer.

**wrap_box.html**

```
<script>
  function create_box(title, content) {
    let summary = document.createElement("summary");
    summary.classList.add("note-header");
    summary.setAttribute("markdown", "1");
    
    let summary_title = document.createTextNode(title)
    let summary_icon = document.createElement('i');
    summary_icon.classList.add("fas", "fa-info-circle");
    summary.append(summary_title, summary_icon);
    
    let div_note_details = document.createElement("div");
    div_note_details.classList.add('note-details');
    div_note_details.append(...content)
    
    let details = document.createElement('details');
    details.append(summary, div_note_details);
    
    let div_note = document.createElement("div");
    div_note.classList.add('note');
    div_note.setAttribute("markdown", "1");
    div_note.append(details);
    return(div_note)
  };
  
  function info_box() {
    let childs = document.querySelectorAll("div.info-box");
    childs.forEach(el => {
      let title = el.title
      let info_box = create_box(title, el.childNodes);
      el.append(info_box)
    });
  };
  
  window.onload = info_box();
</script>
```

---

[image: screenshot of output]

---

Comment: Nice, this is working like a charm!

Comment: I'm packaging up your solution together with my own tweaks of `md_document()` in a very small package [hugodownplus](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/hugodownplus). Since the info box is basically your implementation I would list you as one of the authors. In case you're interested get in touch. Alternatively, I can just mention you in the credits, whatever works fine for you.

Comment: @TimTeaFan, I would be happy to be one of the authors of an R package. : )

Comment: Cool, just get in touch with me (my GitHub profile has all the links) regarding the author details and I'll list you in the description!

Comment: @TimTeaFan, I have just forked your repo and wanted to dm you in Twitter but not seeing any option to do so.