# Generate Rmarkdown report based on child document and list of variable names

Tags: r, dynamic, r-markdown, lapply

I need to do an analysis where I perform the same statistics on a whole stack of columns from a tibble. I would like to generate a single report, where there is a table of contents to view the results for each column (variable). I am struggling to pass the variable correctly to the child Rmarkdown document. I've reproduced my problem using the iris dataset

Child file anova.Rmd:
---
title: "Anova analysis on iris data."
output:
html_document:
df_print: paged
params:
var_name: "Sepal.Length"
---

````
Anova to quantify effect of species on iris data.

## Load libraries
```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(rstatix)
```

## Read in iris data
```{r}
data(iris)
```

### Boxplot
```{r}
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = !!params$var_name, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_minimal()
```

### Anova
```{r}
anova_result <- iris %>%
  anova_test(!!as.name(params$var_name) ~ Species)
print(anova_result)
```
````

Master file to run on all the iris variables:

````
---
title: "Full analysis"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

## Load libraries
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```

```{r loop, results="asis"}
var_names <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")

results <- lapply(var_names, function(var_name) {
  cat("# ", var_name, "\n\n")
  knit_child("anova_db.Rmd", 
  envir = environment(),
  var_name = var_name
  )
})

cat(unlist(results), sep = '\n')
```
````

I am getting this error:

```
Quitting from lines 15-26 (render.Rmd) 
Error in knit(..., tangle = opts_knit$get("tangle"), envir = envir) : 
  unused argument (var_name = "Sepal.Length")
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> lapply -> FUN -> knit_child
In addition: Warning message:
In do_once((if (is_R_CMD_check()) stop else warning)("The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please ",  :
  The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please consider using base::isFALSE(x) or identical(x, FALSE) instead.
Execution halted
```

Comment: Maybe the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655915/how-do-i-knit-child-documents-with-parameters-into-a-main-rmarkdown-document) can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I knit child documents with parameters into a main RMarkdown document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655915/how-do-i-knit-child-documents-with-parameters-into-a-main-rmarkdown-document)